# Google Chrome and Chromium turn white randomly after browsing for sometime

Tags: google-chrome

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64bit and Google Chrome is my default browser. My computer has a Intel core i3 processor and 3GB of RAM. Chrome turns white **RANDOMLY** while browsing and have to reload the page manually. Dual booting this machine with Windows 10 and no problem there.Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: This is a chromium bug. I am afraid it can't be resolved without changng chromium code.

Comment: Have you tried disabling GPU hardware acceleration?  Go into the Chrome settings, go down to Show Advanced Settings, untick the checkbox "Use hardware acceleration when available" and see if it happens again.

Comment: I have seen that a couple of times on my Google Chrome on the dev channel but I can't really reproduce it. If you can reproduce the bug, consider filing a bug report at http://crbug.com.

Comment: Make sure all chrome windows are closed and that chrome isn't running on background and then run from terminal `google-chrome|& tee -a chrome.txt` (maybe you need google-chrome-stable instead of just google-chrome). This will save the output of the `google-chrome` command (the errors too) to `chrome.txt` and when the issue happens then see what errors you get there and edit your question so that we have more info.

Comment: @edwinksl I can reproduce this on stable Chrome with some hardware

Comment: @Pilot6 Good to know :). Have you filed a bug report at http://crbug.com yet?

Comment: No I did not. I am a bit lazy.

Comment: @Dorian I tried unchecking hardware acceleration but didn't help.

Comment: @Nuwan forgot to mention, but you need to restart Chrome after unchecking that box...