# Why is Google Chrome screen flickering?

Tags: google-chrome, screen

I have Google Chrome on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. The screen will occasionally be flickering weirdly. Almost like when I take a screen shot the screen goes white really quickly is what Google Chrome does. How can I make this not happen?

Comment: In Chrome options, try expanding advanced options and turning off hardware acceleration. Then, close Chrome, wait a minute, and try it again.

Comment: @Olathe have done will try :)

Comment: I am facing the same problem on Chrome and Chromium.. [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/790244/google-chrome-and-chromium-turn-white-randomly-after-browsing-for-sometime) is my question and did not get a complete answer..

Comment: What video adapter are you using?

Comment: how do I find out? @Stormlord

Comment: You can open a terminal window and type `lspci -k`.  Find the section `VGA compatible controller` and edit your question to show the results in that section.

Comment: @stormlord http://hastebin.com/catuquwohu.sm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had similar screen flickering issues in Chrome while running Ubuntu 16.04 and with an Intel-based integrated video chipset (i915).

Here's the solution thread that worked for me: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=606152#c72

Note comments #72 and #73. I followed **ONLY** Step 1 of comment #72 and it appears to have worked. Here's that solution:

> sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
>
> Section "Device"
>     Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
>     Driver "intel"
>     Option "AccelMethod"  "sna"
>     Option "TearFree" "true"
>     Option "DRI" "3" 
>   EndSection
>
> restart

Comment: NOTE that the quoted section seems to disregard line-breaks, so be careful in making your edits. Better to view the link solution directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove xorg video driver. It can be reinstalled

```
sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg-video*
sudo reboot
```